# KeyPressed event is called multiple times

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a `jTextField` and added a key listener to it. So, if I type something and press **Enter** key, the `keypressed` event will be called and then I will save whatever is typed.

But, if I press **Enter** key, it is called 3 times.

```
tPatientName.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
              if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                  System.out.println("Saved Successfully");
              }
        }
    });
```

**Console output:**

```
Saved Successfully
Saved Successfully
Saved Successfully
```

I don't know what is wrong in my code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works just fine for me. Post a [mcve] so we can verify what else could be wrong.

Comment: This is the complete reproducible example, it's all the code I have.

Comment: What is tPatientName? Where is it being displayed, what is your main method. Just create a .java file with a JFrame, JTextField, and add they keyListener.

Comment: tPatientName is a `jTextField`. I have it inside a `JTable` as a column

Comment: But I am sure that there is only one keylistener for this text field. 100% sure. Anyways, I will check again.

Comment: Well, the info that you have it inside a `JTable` is actually important, because that's where the source for that behavior might be...

Comment: It printed the object's code. I don't know what to do with it. I am really pissed off.

Comment: @DmanCannon is it the same "object" code, or do the numbers change. What you should do, is try to make a minimal example that reproduces the problem. One of the answers has a minimal example that you can compile and run very easily. Did you try it to see if you get the same error? If it works in that example you need to find the difference.

Comment: @matt I see different numbers in the object code. The minimal example worked fine. I printed just once.

Comment: The number doesn't  change, you are adding multiple listeners. If you click more than once, you should see the same 3 numbers repeating..

Comment: The nums are same now. After removing the `static` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason for it. I have declared the `jTextField` as static.

I had it like this:

```
public static JTextField tPatientName= new JTextField();
```

After removing the `static` keyword it worked.

But, why `static` keyword do this?

Comment: Ill go out on a limb again, the  class with tPatientName field is being used more than once. So you have one or two instances. When you create a new instance of that class, it is using the same 'tPatientName' field as all of the other instances are. That is what `static` does, it ties the field to the class, not to an instance.

Comment: *"I have declared the `jTextField` as static."* Oh you mean the text field not mentioned in the uncompilable code snippet you claimed was *"..the complete reproducible example, it's all the code I have."*? It's stuff like this that makes posting a [mre] so useful. If you had, someone would likely have spotted the problem within 3 minutes, rather than the better part of 3 hours it took. *"I am really pissed off."* Post a well researched, well expressed question in future, and you won't likely ever need to feel p'd off. Take the time, it'll pay off.

Answer (score 1):

I created a `MRE` based on what you're telling us and it works without any problems whatsoever. Feel free to compare whatever mysterious code that you can't share with us with my little example.

```java
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class EnterKeyTest
{
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JTextField tPatientName;
    
    public EnterKeyTest()
    {
        initGUI();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EnterKeyTest e = new EnterKeyTest();
    }
    
    private void initGUI()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        
        tPatientName = new JTextField(15);
        tPatientName.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    System.out.println("Saved Successfully");
                }
            }
        });
        
        panel.add(tPatientName);
        frame.add(panel);
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, what? What is good practice then? I'm still a junior developer and literally every single program my company made has some `initGUI()` call in some constructor.

Comment: Hm that does make sense. We do always use dedicated GUI classes though, so that might be why we feel no real danger of reference leaks. It does atleast conceptually make sense to me that a dedicated GUI class would initialize the GUI creation in it's constructor. Thanks for the food for thought either way though!

Comment: Your code works fine, and mine is exactly the same. but, it causes problems

Comment: In the future, start your Swing application with a call to the SwingUtilities invokeLater method so you create and execute Swing components on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Answer (score 0):

Does changing keyPressed() to keyReleased() help?

Comment: I tried it already, it didn't work.